# Trouble with populating data on two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

Please help.

I have two tables.

> **subcat**
>
> id,   user_id,    subcat_id,  title,  description,    price, best_offer,
>     image,  zip,    premium_listing,    status,     date_create,d date_modified

and

> **aditem**
>
> id,   user_id,    subcat_id , title,  descriptio,n    pric,e  best_offer
>   image, zip,   premium_listing,    status,     date_created,   date_modified

I am trying to list all the categories in subcat and count the number of ad items that have been posted into aditem that relates to  id in subcat

so results could look like this

> auto - 7
>
> junk cars -9
>
> clothing - 10
>
> bikes - 0

I have tried LEFT JOIN but it did not work. is there are way to accomplish this? Would UNION work?

here is an example of what i want to accomplish: http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=13

Here is what i have tried

```
   SELECT  subcat.id, subcat.cat_id, subcat.subcat, subcat.description AS subdesc, COUNT(aditem.subcat_id) AS itemc 
     FROM subcat
LEFT JOIN aditem  
       ON aditem.subcat_id = subcat.id
```

thanks a million
Earnest

Comment: When you say "it did not work" - what happened?  looks like you're missing a group by clause, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a COUNT(*) statement in there. Something like

```
SELECT subcat.title, COUNT(aditem.id) AS count FROM subcat LEFT JOIN aditem ON subcat_id = subcat.id
```

You might need this at the end; not sure and can't test right now:

```
GROUP BY aditem.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT subcat.id, subcat.cat_id, subcat.subcat, subcat.description AS subdesc,    COUNT(aditem.id) AS itemc FROM subcat LEFT JOIN aditem ON aditem.subcat_id = subcat.id
GROUP BY subcat.cat_id
```

Comment: You can use Order BY column_name clause. Could you provide example of this ordering?

Comment: Try to use GROUP BY aditem.cat_id

Comment: Here is the update one i have tried. result only show one subcat in each cat



    "SELECT subcat.id, subcat.cat_id, subcat.subcat, subcat.description AS subdesc,    COUNT(aditem.id) AS itemc FROM subcat LEFT JOIN aditem ON aditem.subcat_id = subcat.id
    WHERE subcat.cat_id = '$catid' GROUP BY subcat.cat_id ");

Comment: got it. here is the answer
"SELECT subcat.id, subcat.cat_id, subcat.subcat, subcat.description AS subdesc,    COUNT(aditem.id) AS itemc FROM subcat LEFT JOIN aditem ON aditem.subcat_id = subcat.id
WHERE subcat.cat_id = '$catid'  GROUP BY subcat.id ");

Comment: Yes this is the same like GROUP BY aditem.cat_id but it should be check on db.